# Can I uninstall Totem?

Tags: 11.10, uninstall, totem

In my opinion, VLC is a much better and much faster player than Totem, and plays everything without having to need all of the extra junk Totem comes with. My question is, can you safely uninstall Totem? I'm trying to reduce the amount of junk on my computer, and since I'm using VLC for all my movie/video objectives, I see no need to have Totem.

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, I've just uninstalled it like this:

`sudo apt-get remove totem`